# Get field of C# list of struct from code behind in Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I would like to access a `List<Records>` where Records is a struct, from a JS script. After a bit of googling (especially [question 29098558](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29098558/asp-net-pass-data-from-code-behind-to-javascript-and-call-array) here) i Json serialized my object and retrieve it in the script.

I should mention it's my first time at JS so syntax may be totally wrong.

In C#

```
  string serializedResults = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(RecordsList);
```

(in my context the records are actually in a `Dictionnary<string, Records>` but i hide the access through dictionnary because i supposed it isn't relevant here)

In Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function setupBarChart() {
        var x = [];
        var y = [];
        var source = "<%= serializedRecords %>";

        // I would like to put Records fields in y and x tab to use it as data for the axes of an histogram.
        for (var i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {

        }  
    }
</script>
```

My questions are :

- what is the type of source ? Is it just a string ? Does it create an equivalent of List in JS ?
- How do I access my Records fields from JS ?
- Does source.length gives me the number of records in the list ??

Comment: Where are you calling `JsonConvert.SerializeObject`? You have declared `serializedResults` but you are trying to use `serializedRecords`. Looks like some typo.

Comment: Some typo indeed, it's serializedRecords. I'm calling SerializeObject from the ascx.cs associated to the ascx file where I write my JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what is the type of source ? Is it just a string ? Does it create an equivalent of List in JS ?

In the code shown, it is a string, but I think the code shown is very wrong - the quotes are incorrect and should be removed, to:

```
var source = <%= serializedRecords %>;
```

(note, I'm not going to opine on encoding in the above, but: be careful and check it is safe)

leaving (in the rendered html):

```
var source = [{"foo":123,"bar":"def"},{...},{...}];
```

now the type is a javascript array.

> How do I access my Records fields from JS ?

via `source`, which is an array

> Does source.length gives me the number of records in the list ??

yes, if you lose the quotes

Comment: Sorry for the wrong syntax, first time at javascript. I understand why the quotes make source a string. However VisualStudio warn me of a syntax error without the quotes, i must have forgotten something else elsewhere.

Comment: @YthioCsi nah, I think Visual Studio is just struggling to parse your intent - does it **work**? I suspect it will

Comment: I wish i could deploy solution but i can't right now... ... ... Anyway, i read the article about JS arrays on W3School website and I wondered if source is an associative array, if so, it tells "all array methods and properties will produce incorrect results", so source.length will return 0 no matter what, doesn't it ? (i can use a foreach instead so it's more a question than a problem)

Comment: @YthioCsi it is just a javascript array - length will work just fine; and no, you can't use a foreach - javascript doesn't *have* a foreach keyword; there are methods like `forEach` or `$.each`, of course

Comment: Would my view update each time the serializedRecords value changed ? Like a INotifyPropertyChange implementation in WPF ?

Comment: @YthioCsi client-side? not without a push API like web-sockets, or a polling check; this isn't something that comes for free in the web world

Comment: If i create an ASP Hidden Field, set my serialized string as its Value, and then do `var source = document.getElementById('HiddenField').value;` the source variable will be the same as previously ?